# convert unix timestamp to datetime in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, couchbase

I index my couchbase documents in elasticsearch (using xdcr). In couchbase, we have fields storing unix timestamps, but I want to index them as date-time in ElasticSearch.
Is there a way to tell elasticsearch to convert unix timestamp (in seconds) to date time?

thanks.

Answer (score 4):

no one answered, so I continued googling and found the answer here:

http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Convert-unix-timestamp-seconds-to-java-milliseconds-td4067144.html

```
{
    "test" : {
"transform" : {
            "script" : "ctx._source['date_created'] = ctx._source['date_created'].toLong() * 1000",
            "lang": "groovy"
        },
        "properties" : {
            "date_created" : {"type" : "date"},
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Transform function in mapping is deprecated since elasticsearch 2.0 due to debugging issues.
The solution might be this:

1. Create a new mapping with updated type (you can get that copy pasted from you current mapping using GET your_index/_mapping). Update you date_created type to "epoch_second"

   `PUT index2
   {
   "mappings": {
     "couchbaseDocument": {
         "properties": {
       "doc" : {
           "properties" : {
               "createdAt" : {"type" : "date","format":"epoch_second"},
               "amount": {
                   "type": "float"
                 },
                 "appGroup": {
                   "type": "long"
                 },
                 "bmi": {
                   "type": "float"
                 },`
2. Use that mapping to reindex from your current index(use script if need to convert data)  :

   `POST _reindex
       {
         "source": {
           "index": "index1"
         },
         "dest": {
           "index": "index2"
         },
         "script": {
           "lang": "painless",
           "inline": "if(ctx._source.doc.createdAt !=null){ ctx._source.doc.createdAt = (long)ctx._source.doc.createdAt}"
         }
       }`